# Do Americans typically get fingerprinted (or other biometric checks) upon successful visa free entry to the UK?

Tags: uk, us-citizens

I suppose the different entry channels might imply different answers, but the more information, the better.

Comment: If you use the e-gates I believe they do face recognition based on the biometrics stored in the e-passport. Wikipedia states this is done manually by an officer comparing the two but that seems pretty weird to me.

Comment: @jcaron It's face recognition with a manual backup if the faces don't match. That's what the officers sitting at the desk behind the gates in most airports are doing, I believe.

Comment: Are all American passports e-passports? And for Americans are the egates mandatory?

Comment: All US passports issued [since August 2007](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_passport) have been e-passports.  The e-gates are not mandatory; you can go to a staffed desk if you prefer, but you may be asked why you chose not to use the e-gate.  I don't know the retention policy of the images captured by the e-gates, but it's probably the same as for the image taken from your passport's chip, which will also be done at the staffed desk.  Travelers between 12 and 17 years old may only use the gates if traveling in the company of an adult; travelers 11 and younger may not use them.

Answer (score 1):

Nope—don't think so. Not unless you already have a biometric visa to begin with.

**Edit** I (US Citizen) did a Master's in the UK and had a biometric visa, so they had my prints. But whenever I just enter for kicks, I never get fingerprinted. Maybe this has changed due to Brexit. Last I entered was March 2020.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think so either, but what is your answer based on? I'm asking to double check because my friend has said there are.

Comment: Are you excluding the passport check itself https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coming-to-the-uk/faster-travel-through-the-uk-border

Comment: "just enter for kicks" - what does this mean?

Comment: @RichardBeasley He's saying that when he enters UK for fun/tourist purposes, they never fingerprint him

Comment: @RichardBeasley Correct. Just for tourist/visit purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. So is your student visa expired, then?

Comment: @JosephP. Yes and I have been back twice since then